# Task Scheduler Create Task DotNet not working

Tags: .net-core, windows-task-scheduler

I am trying to schedule a task using Task Scheduler on Windows. It is for a console app written with .net Core. I have created a task, set a trigger and created a new action.

When I manually run it, I get a 'Last Run Result' of **'The system cannot find the file specified. (0x80070002)'**. I have ensured that the user account running the task has access to the database on SQL Server.

I ran it in the command line as **dotnet  "C:\Program Files\UTDT_Database_Update\publish\UTDT_Database_Update.dll"** and it worked successfully.

My 'Edit Action' is as follows.

**Program/Script:** dotnet

**Add arguments (optional):** UTDT_Database_Update.dll

**Start in (optional):** C:\Program Files\UTDT_Database_Update\publish\

I haven't found any solutions that work yet. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: can you try putting path in "" for example: "C:\Program Files\UTDT_Database_Update\publish\" in start in of task as path contains space in it.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have tried that but it returns **Directory Name is Invalid**. I googled that error and it found that Start in (optional) field doesn't support quotes. The user said it worked for him without quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to create a batch file (.bat) that contained the following:

```
@ECHO OFF dotnet "C:\Program files\UTDT_Database_Update\publish\UTDT_Database_Update.dll"
```

**Program/Script:** UTDT_Database_Update_batch.bat

**Add arguments:** *empty*

**Start in:** *Location of .bat file*

This made it run. Still not sure why original task didn't work but this at least gets it to run.